# How to associate a row in a ListView with an object in collection?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple 3-column ListView. This control is programatically populated with data from a collection (a generic List) I'd like to use double click event on every row in this ListView to open another form. This form will display data which are in clicked row and will be also used to edit these data so I need access to proper object in collection. But I have no idea how to make a some sort of connection between a row in ListView and specific object in collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag.aspx) property, which exists exactly for that purpose.

From MSDN:

> Gets or sets an object that contains data to associate with the item.

To retrieve the data object, just cast the `Tag` property to the type of the object.